# Salesforce Developer Console malfunctioning

Tags: developer-console

My developer console is not showing any Logs sometimes. It would not show any logs for hours, and then suddenly go back to working normal, and in another few hours, back to not showing Logs.

For example, I just ran

```
System.debug('Test');
```

from the anonymous window of the developer console with `Open Log` checked, but no log opens, and the log panel stays empty. This problem has been there for three days.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the log level and setting the time to 'sometime later'. Don't know why logging stops but this seems to fix it.